# NSXMLParser divides strings containing foreign(unicode) characters

Tags: iphone, utf-8, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I have ran into a peculiar problem with NSXMLParser.

For some reason it cuts out all the characters in front of all the norwegian characters æ, ø and å.

However, the problem seems to be the same with all non a-z characters.(All foreign characters)

Examples:

Reality: Mål
Output: ål

Reality: Le chant des sirènes
Output: ènes

Heres an example from the log where I have printed out the string from:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

Log:

```
2012-02-22 14:00:01.647 VotePlayClient[2776:207] found characters: Le chant des sir
2012-02-22 14:00:01.647 VotePlayClient[2776:207] found characters: ènes
```

You can clearly see that it jumps to a new line whenever it encounters a foreign letter.

I believe that I have to figure out how to append the string or something to that effect.

Here are the NSXMLParser files:

SearchXMLParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Search.h"

@interface SearchXMLParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSMutableArray *searchhits;
NSMutableArray *trackhits;

NSXMLParser *parser;
Search *currentSearch;  
}

@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableArray *searchhits;
@property (readonly, retain) NSMutableArray *trackhits;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;

@end
```

SearchXMLParser.m

```
#import "SearchXMLParser.h"
#import "Search.h"

@implementation SearchXMLParser

@synthesize searchhits, trackhits;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    searchhits          = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
trackhits           = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
return self;    
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"track"]) 
{
    currentSearch = [Search alloc];
}

if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"track"]) 
{
    currentSearch.trackurl = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
}
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{   
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"]) 
{
    [trackhits addObject:currentNodeContent];

}

if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"track"]) 
{
    currentSearch.track = [trackhits objectAtIndex:0];
    currentSearch.artist = [trackhits objectAtIndex:1];
    currentSearch.album = [trackhits objectAtIndex:2];
    [trackhits removeAllObjects];

    [searchhits addObject:currentSearch];
    [currentSearch release];
    currentSearch = nil;
    [currentNodeContent release];
    currentNodeContent = nil;
}
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
[parser release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I have already checked SO for answers and found a couple of similar posts, but nothing that gave a clear solution to this problem.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem? :) Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: use a mutable string to append characters found, flush (reset) it when the element is ended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your parser:foundCharacters: method does not work as it should.

This is from the [NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-SW12)

> The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, **you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes**.

you could try something like this (ARC):

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    if (!currentNodeContent) {
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{   
    // your code here

    // when you are done with the string:
    currentNodeContent = nil;
}
```