# How to handle a tags inside another tags in NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I have a file:

```
<xml>
    <component>something
        <system>somethingDeeper
            <value>somethingDeepest</value>
        </system>
    </component>

    <component>somethinfDifferent
        <value>somethingDifferentDeeper</value>
    </component>

    <value>somethingNew</value>
</xml>
```

So I want to distinguish what is inside another tag (ex. `<system>`) what is not. How to do this with **NSXMLParser**? I currently use BOOL ivar's but this is a lot of tags and this is not as elegant as I want it to be. I know that NSXMLParser is a SAX parser and I understand that.

In above example I will be enter to `didEndElement` method three times with:
`elementName` equal `value` Is there a more elegant way to distinguish what entry was from `<component>` tag above what not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep an array of tag names you are currently within

```
NSMutableArray *tagNameStack;
```

Each time you enter a new element you add it to this array. Each time you leave you remove it again. i.e.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    [tagNameStack addObject:elementName];

    // Your code here
}
```

and

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    // Your code here

    [tagNameStack removeLastObject];
}
```

So, when you are parsing `somethingDeepest` your tagNameStack array would be

```
@"xml", @"component", @"system", @"value"
```

You can use this stack to decide where you are in the xml i.e.

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if ([tagNameStack containsObject:@"system"]) {
        // Deal with the value inside the system tag
    } else if ([tagNameStack containsObject:@"component"]) {
        // Deal with the value inside the component tag
    } else {
        // This must be the value inside the XML tag
    }
}
```

Comment: This is partly helpful, but as far i understand in my case i have one stack becouse everything is inside <xml> tag. So there how can i decide where is end tag? Value tak is the last, but i can don't know that.. Another problem is with if ([tagNameStack containsObject:@"system"]) with system i'm calling? There is no way i can tell that.

Comment: Every XML document will only have one stack, there can only ever be one root node! Each time you enter a `<value>` tag, you can ask the stack if you got there via a `component` or a `system` or just `xml` - that's just looking into the items in your array.

Comment: See my edited answer - I've tried to make my `didEndElement` method clearer so you can see how the stack can be used to detect which `<value>` tag you are ending.

Comment: Ooooh, I modify your answer to create an objects in didStartElement, put it into stack, and remove in didEndElement. Your answer was a huge clue. Thanks. Bounty is yours :) ( i have to wayt 18 more hours).

Comment: @Greeso - your edit has a bug - `parser:foundCharacters:` can be called more than once during the parse of an element (i.e. if it's a large chunk of text) or it might not be called at all (i.e. if the element is empty `<empty></empty>`). Annoyingly your edit has been approved already, any chance you can change it back (or add a comment warning people that this might happen!)

Comment: @deanWombourne - It is tested and it works. This is why there is the 'if' statement to take care of that fact you raised. If this method is called more than once due to having a large text, then you have to append your text; you have to do something as described in the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396391/nsxmlparser-divides-strings-containing-foreignunicode-characters

Comment: It works _most of the time_ - can you show me your tests showing it working with (a) empty, (b) very large and (c) CDATA filled elements? :) How do you deal with empty elements where this method isn't called at all - no `if` statements can help you there! If you want to something with an element's contents once and only once, use `didFinish` - that's what that delegate method is there for. If you want to stream content and parse on the fly then use `foundCharacters`. The comments in your `if` show that you want to deal with a finished value _which you are not guaranteed to have at this point_!

Comment: @deanWombourne - You are talking about special cases that do require  special attention. That said, I believe using 'parser:foundCharacters:' is more appropriate for this answer, as it gives a clearer explanation of how to deal with XML. That said, answers provided in SO are a general understanding, and specifics should be considered when you write your own code.

Comment: @deanWombourne - One other note, modifying your original code does not mean you had it wrong. Kudos to you for coming up with that idea, but I believe it can be enhanced by my suggestion. Cheer up.