# Where is my mistake in my code for display on tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried load an array from web service and display on table view.This my tableview.But there is a mistake.Branchnames are

MEHMET FUDAYLÖZCAN,

SELAHATTİN KOÇAK,

Mehmet Süner Eken Petrol

Hasan Katkıcı Petrol

etc

etc

but table view show me like that

How I fix this ?

[image]

Th
Array Codes :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchname"] )
  {
    teveRetorno = YES;
  }
  else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetBranchNameResult"] )
  {
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
  if (teveRetorno) {
    //[retornoSOAP appendString:string];
    [myArray addObject:string];
  }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Branchname"] ) {
    NSLog(@"My Array %@",myArray);

    [[self tableView]reloadData];

    //retornoSOAP = nil;
    teveRetorno = NO;
  }
}
```

Table Codes

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  #warning Incomplete method implementation.
  // Return the number of rows in the section.

  return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text =[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is it the case you want to know why the text is being truncated?  Try setting `cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES`.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Yes I want that.And I want display in one row.I added your code and result is here http://picpaste.com/ekranson-6HXwMH0I.png

Comment: So is your issue resolved?

Comment: @jeffamaphone No. I think XML Parser can not parse illegal characters(Ö,İ,Ü,Ş,ı)

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape those at the source?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your table view or output.  Your XMLParser is getting confused by certain characters (Ö) and calling didStartElement too early.  Check out this - [NSXMLParser divides strings containing foreign(unicode) characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396391/nsxmlparser-divides-strings-containing-foreignunicode-characters)

Answer (score 0):

If your asking about the reason the text is getting cut off, set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth for the textLabel of the cell. If that dosent fix it, then manually lower the font of the textLabel.